# How can I avoid entering duplicate entries in my MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So, what I'm trying to do here is check the `user` table in my `users` mySQL database for duplicate entries in the `username` row, before inserting a new `username.` Here's an example of my code. Currently, the results ResultSet does not do anything and I'm not exactly sure how to implement it into the IF statement that follows.  And yes, I have the catches for the `try`, just not in this example. Sorry if this is a rather simple question, I just started programming with Java last week. Also, it's my first question on here and I definitely appreciate the help.

```
 try{


      String sequel = ("SELECT username FROM `users`.`user`");
      PreparedStatement userNameInfo = conn.prepareStatement(sequel);
      userNameInfo.executeQuery(sequel);
      ResultSet results = userNameInfo.getResultSet();

      if (sequel.equals("")) {
          conn.setAutoCommit(false);
          String sql = "INSERT INTO `users`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES('" + newusername +"', '" + newpassword + "', '" + newemail +"')";
          PreparedStatement prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          prest.executeUpdate(sql);
          conn.commit();
          conn.close();
          System.out.println("Added Successfully!");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Add failed!");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please read up on [Primary key concept](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think what you trying to do - and should do I think, is select if the username is in the table then add or not.  So the sql needs to be like:

select username from users where username = ?

then set the param in the query. See docs here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

You then need to check what is in the resultset after the query, and see if anything is in there.  The API docs for this will be in about the same place as the PreparedStatement docs.

Adding a constraint in the db will also give you a belt and braces.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I understand the overall concept of what you're saying, but, I'll be honest, I don't really how or what parameter to set in the query haha. I'm assuming there must be some way to say `if _newusername_ !=` existing `username` then submit it to the database, `else system.out.print("Username is already taken);` and then loop back.

Comment: Added a link to the API docs.  The parameter you want to set is the username that you want to test.  Effectively you are asking the DB if it already knows of the name the new user wants to use.

Answer (score 2):

When you define your SQL table, you can define some items to be unique.

So in your example, if you want usernames to be unique, you would add:

```
UNIQUE(username)
```

to your table declaration.

If you want the pair username / email to be unique, you would add:

```
UNIQUE(username, email)
```

The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the primary key in the table? A primary key automatically prevents duplicate values.

If you want to prevent duplicate usernames, then make your `username` column the primary key.

Comment: The problem with that is, to the best of my knowledge (and I'm new to this) there can only be one auto incremental and it has to be the primary key. I want the idUser to continually increment with each new input of `username.` Though, I suppose that maybe the idUser column is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, I am not a java guy. But this may help you.

You can retrieve the row count of the first result set after the query executes. If the row count is equal to 0, that means database does not contain a similar record.